# angular-cli 25.5 Module build failed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

#### Problem

After updating angular-cli from 22.1 to 25.5 (installing angular-cli@latest) and from angular 2.2.3 to 2.3.1 I've got this problem:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at IdentifierObject.TokenOrIdentifierObject.getText (~/projects/MyProject/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:53644:56)
    at ~/projects/MyProject/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:83:72
    at Array.some (native)
    at ~/projects/MyProject/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:83:32
    at Array.filter (native)
    at _removeModuleId (~/projects/MyProject/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:82:10)
    at ~/projects/MyProject/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:167:48
 @ ./src/main.ts 5:0-45
 @ multi main
```

But I cannot figure out what the problem is, the `main.ts` looks normal:

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

There are two other files which are also failing with the exact same error message as above, 1st the `environment.ts` with nothing special in it and 2nd a sub module which failed with the addition of:

```
 @ ./src async
 @ ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
 @ ./~/@angular/core/src/linker.js
 @ ./~/@angular/core/src/core.js
 @ ./~/@angular/core/index.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

---

#### NodeModules SourceCode

The referred `typescript.js:53644:56` looks like this:

```
[53643] TokenOrIdentifierObject.prototype.getText = function (sourceFile) {
[53644]     return (sourceFile || this.getSourceFile()).text.substring(this.getStart(), this.getEnd());
[53645] };
```

and `loader.js:83:72` & `83:32` refers to webpack and this code snippet:

```
[078] exports.removeModuleIdOnlyForTesting = removeModuleIdOnlyForTesting;
[...] function _removeModuleId(refactor) {
[...]   var sourceFile = refactor.sourceFile;
[...]   refactor.findAstNodes(sourceFile, ts.SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression, true)
[...]       .filter(function (node) {
[083]       return node.properties.some(function (prop) { return prop.name.getText() == 'moduleId'; });
[...]   })
[...]       .forEach(function (node) {
[...]       var moduleIdProp = node.properties.filter(function (prop, idx) {
[...]           return prop.name.getText() == 'moduleId';
[...]       })[0];
[...]       // get the trailing comma
[...]       var moduleIdCommaProp = moduleIdProp.parent.getChildAt(1).getChildren()[1];
[...]       refactor.removeNodes(moduleIdProp, moduleIdCommaProp);
[...]   });
[093] }
```

and `loader.js:167:48`

```
[148] // Super simple TS transpiler loader for testing / isolated usage. does not type check!
[...] function ngcLoader(source) {
[...]   this.cacheable();
[...]   var cb = this.async();
[...]   var sourceFileName = this.resourcePath;
[...]   var plugin = this._compilation._ngToolsWebpackPluginInstance;
[...]   // We must verify that AotPlugin is an instance of the right class.
[...]   if (plugin && plugin instanceof plugin_1.AotPlugin) {
[...]       var refactor_2 = new refactor_1.TypeScriptFileRefactor(sourceFileName, plugin.compilerHost, plugin.program);
[...]       Promise.resolve()
[...]           .then(function () {
[...]           if (!plugin.skipCodeGeneration) {
[...]               return Promise.resolve()
[...]                   .then(function () { return _removeDecorators(refactor_2); })
[...]                   .then(function () { return _replaceBootstrap(plugin, refactor_2); });
[...]           }
[...]           else {
[...]               return Promise.resolve()
[...]                   .then(function () { return _replaceResources(refactor_2); })
[167]                   .then(function () { return _removeModuleId(refactor_2); });
[...]           }
[169]       })
[...]  ...
```

#### Question

Has anybody had the same problem or can figure out why webpack(?) fails - or can explain to me what the compiler is trying to do and why it fails?

#### Edit

`angular-cli.json`:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.25.5",
    "name": "myproject"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "assets/css/main.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "assets/lib/stomp.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev":    "environments/environment.ts",
        "live": "environments/environment.live.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error says the problem is in app.module.ts, yet that is the source code you do not include in your question.

Comment: Make sure you reference all your source files in the "include" and "files" sections of "tsconfig.json"

Comment: Could you please post your angular-cli.json?

Comment: I changed the name of my project to lower case - after that I was able to see and fix some issues which came from a stricter typescript linting, after trying to fix `stompjs` typings I got the same error messages again (without the 'real' error messages) - will update my post

Comment: @R.Richards: I don't think the `AppModule` is the culprit here - I can post this also if you think it's important ...

Comment: Same problem here. My project ran fine until I added a module generated by the Angular CLI. Adding the new module to the imports section of the `AppModule` makes the error message go away. It seems that the webpack (?) fails to load the source file. However, I don't understand why. I didn't find the difference to the other modules in my project yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build error in angular2 frontend using angular-cli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672828/build-error-in-angular2-frontend-using-angular-cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update:

As @stewdebaker noted: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26 has now been released and appears to fix this issue.

---

As @stewdebaker mentioned there is a similar question [Build error in angular2 frontend using angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707710/931485) - the solution there was to just revert to `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21`.

Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4072 for more information on the issue in the `angular-cli` issue tracker.

---

I wasn't able to to fix my project and also I was not able to revert to my previous `angular-cli` version `1.0.0-beta.22-1` (and I didn't see the other questioned asked on Stack Overflow, otherwise I probably would have tried to revert to `1.0.0-beta.21`).

For some reason before updating to `1.0.0-beta.25.5` the `ng serve` command was working but after reverting to `1.0.0-beta.22-1` it would still bring up the same errors as after the update.

#### Time-Consuming Solution

So I decided to create a new Angular2 project with the `angular-cli` and rebuild the whole project with the CLI while copying the code from the old repository and fixing bugs.

The bugs I encountered were minor issues (I think they're a result of the changed `tslint.json` due to the updated `angular-cli`) but nothing big was changed in the project and now it works.

The source files mentioned in the error messages:

- app.module.ts
- tsconfig.json
- angular-cli.json

haven't changed a bit but the `angular-cli` is usable again, `ng serve` now runs without encountering errors.

I don't think this is the ideal solution (nor is downgrading to `1.0.0-beta.21`) - but that's the only thing I could find.

Comment: `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26` has now been released and appears to fix this issue.